# Micronaut Hibernate JPA MariaDB - saveAll 20K data High CPU usage

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am using Micronaut Hibernate JPA, and MariaDB as database in my project. I use JPA repositories for database transactions. I receive lots of data (20K-100K) each second and I need to save them to a table. I use saveAll method in CrudRepository interface. But when I save the data CPU overhead increases a lot. I made a research and I think if I use second level cache, it can help decrease the CPU overhead.

1. What should  do to enable and use second level cache?
2. I think there is "ehcache". What would be the yml configuration file and
3. What would be the additional dependencies that I can add to my Maven pom file?

Comment: What exactly is the "overhead", I'm assuming its within MariaDB, but what part? What table structures? What to do the updates look like? What MariaDB version? Configuration? Hardware? What are your read requests like? Can they tolerate delayed data? Usually, before going for a cache, is to optimize what you already have.